# jelastic + jetty, помогите понять механику работы и способ деплоя

Tags: java, сервер, jetty

Я создал maven проект, расставил зависимости, написал простенький сервер, по типу "hello, world", который просто отдаёт страницы. Руководствовался информацией с курсов степик. Поскольку там минимум информации, просто не могу понять как поставить готовый проект на jelastic. Там есть возможность при создании облака установить jetty, но там уже будет готовый сервер, а мне нужно как-то поставить свой. Гугл-поиски ни к чему не приводят, я даже не понимаю как составить запрос.

Помогите понять как поставить jetty сервер на jelastic.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте рассмотрим следующий пример развертывания **Java**-приложения посредством **Maven-плагина** на платформе **Jelastic**.

Предлагаем, выполнить несколько простых шагов:

**Шаг 1 - Создание окружения.**

Пожалуйста залогиньтесь в Ваш дашборд и нажмите на кнопку **"New Environment"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В окне настроек окружения, пожалуйста выберите Java, затем **Tomcat 7 Server**, введите уникальное имя Вашего окружения, например - **"Maventest"** и укажите необходимое количество клаудлетов для Вашего окружения. В завершении данного шага, нажмите на кнопку **"Create"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ваше окружение будет создано в течении нескольких минут.

**Шаг 2 - Создание простого проекта веб-приложения через IntelliJ iDEA.**

Пожалуйста, откройте среду разработки **IntelliJ IDEA** на Вашем компьютере (*среда разработки должна быть предварительно установлена*) и создайте новый проект через меню **"File -> New"**. В появившемся окне, укажите тип проекта **Project SDK** (например **v1.8**), отметьте чекбокс **"Create from archetype"** и из выпадающего списка выберите **"maven-archetype-webapp:Release"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем нажмите кнопку **"Next"** и заполните поля **"GroupID"** и **"ArtifactID"**, например **"demo-jelastic"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь, пожалуйста укажите домашнюю директорию проекта (рекомендуется Bundled (Maven 3)) и проставьте чекбоксы как на скриншоте ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пожалуйста, запомните или сохраните где-либо путь к файлу **settings.xml**. Данный путь пригодится нам позже.

Также, укажите имя проекта и рабочую директорию и нажмите кнопку **"Finish"**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь необходимо немного подождать, пока структура проекта полностью создастся. Данный процесс, обычно занимает около пяти минут. Вы можете наблюдать за процессом внутри терминала Вашей среды разработки. После завершения, структура проекта будет выглядеть следующим образом:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 3 - Редактируем файл web.xml**

Пожалуйста откройте файл web.xml внутри Вашего проекта и замените его содержимое на следующий код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee
         http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Стоит обратить внимание на ссылки которые могут быть подсвечены красным цветом. Если это так, то пожалуйста, перейдите в меню **"File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Schemas and DTDs"** и добавьте необходимые ссылки в **"Ignored Schemas and DTDs"**. Пример ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Шаг 4 - Редактирование файла settings.xml**

Пожалуйста. откройте терминал Вашей ОС и перейдите в папку **"/home/$username$/.m2"** (наиболее правильный путь к файлу мы сохраняли ранее). Откройте файл **settings.xml** (или создайте, если он не существует) и замените его содержимое на следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>jelastic</id>
      <properties>
        <jelastic.username>[insert your Jelastic user name]</jelastic.username>
        <jelastic.password>[insert your Jelastic password]</jelastic.password>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</settings>
```

Пожалуйста, укажите Ваш логин и пароль к Вашему дашборду внутри директив **"jelastic.username"** и **"jelastic.password"**. Не забудьте сохранить изменения в файле.

**Шаг 5 - Редактирование файла pom.xml**

Давайте вернемся в структуру проекта и выберем файл **"pom.xml"**. Замените его содержимое на текст ниже:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>demo-jelastic</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-jelastic</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo-jelastic Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
      <finalName>demo-jelastic</finalName>
    </build>
    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>sonatype-oss-public</id>
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public</url>
        <releases>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
      </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    <profiles>
      <profile>
        <id>jelastic</id>
        <build>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.jelastic</groupId>
              <artifactId>jelastic-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.7</version>
              <configuration>
                <api_hoster>[INSERT YOUR HOSTER'S API ADRESS]</api_hoster>
                <context>ROOT</context>
                <email>[YOUR EMAIL]</email>
                <environment>[ENVIRONMENT NAME]</environment>
                <password>[PASSWORD]</password>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>install</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>deploy</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
              <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.4</version>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <phase>none</phase>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </build>
      </profile>
    </profiles>
  </project>
```

Внутри директивы **"configuration"** укажите следующие директивы:
**"api_hoster"** - [URL-адрес](https://docs.jelastic.com/jelastic-hoster-info) Вашего дашборда.
**"email"** и "password" - учетные данные, которые используются для входа в дашбод.
**"environment"** - имя ранее созданного окружения.

Сохраните изменения в файле (**File -> Save all**)

**Шаг 6 - Развертывание веб-приложения в облако Jelastic.**

В панели **"Maven Projects"** выберите профиль **"Jelastic"** и **"Install"** в списке **lifecycle**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нажмите на кнопку **"Run Maven Build"** и наблюдайте за процессом внутри терминала среды разработки. Как результат - работающее простое веб-приложение внутри облака **Jelastic**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В таком случае куда кладутся сервлеты?